# Databricks- ConcurrentAppendException:

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I'm running like 20 notebooks concurrently and they all update the same Delta table (however, different rows). I'm getting the below exception if any two notebooks try to update the table at the same time).

Does setting `'delta.isolationLevel' = 'Serializable'` for the Delta table fix the issue? Is there a better option?

> ConcurrentAppendException: Files were added to the root of the table by a concurrent update. Please try the operation again. Conflicting commit:

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same issue, but I'm not sure changing the isolation level will help you in this case.
Talking to the Databricks dev team, the best solution for that is to partition your data in a way that no two writes happen on the same partition.
For example, you have `df.repartition('full_name')` and you can guarantee that no two notebooks update or delete the same `full_name`. Insert (append) operations should be safe.

Refer to: https://docs.delta.io/latest/concurrency-control.html#avoid-conflicts-using-partitioning-and-disjoint-command-conditions

If you can't redesign your application in this way, you might have to catch the `ConcurrenAppendException`, wait a little bit and retry.